# Google Cloud Trace doesn't correlate logs from Spring Boot applications using Sleuth

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud-sleuth, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-trace

I've recently upgraded my applications to Spring Boot 2.4.2, Cloud 2020.0.0, changing Spring Cloud GCP dependencies following the migration guide: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/2.0.0/reference/html/index.html#migration-guide-from-spring-cloud-gcp-1-x-to-2-x

Regarding the applications everything seems to be working fine. I can see calls between the microservices propagating the trace-id headers:

gateway:

```
2021-01-24 20:18:36.471 DEBUG [gateway,0bc6b9664e6604e2,eb9f834718fe33c9] 1 ---
```

service1:

```
2021-01-24 20:18:36.700 DEBUG [service1,0bc6b9664e6604e2,570653ac93add270,true]
```

In the Google Cloud Trace console I can see that the trace id (`0bc6b9664e6604e2`) was captured (prefixed with 16 extra 0's) and that it shows both microservices (the first post corresponds to gateway and the third call correspons to service1:

[image]

However notice the message "No logs found for this trace".

Also the Trace Logs View link complaints about it:

[image]

If I open the link it just looks by timestamp, not using the correlation trace id.

The funny thing is if I look for a log statement directly in the GCP Logging view, the trace id is there:

[image]

I can then run a GCP Logging query to find all the logs correctly:

[image]

Apparently everything seems to be OK. Could you tell why GCP Trace isn't able to correlate with GCP Logging?

Answer (score 1):

For the logs to appear correlated with tracing you need to add the stackdriver log dependency (I think it only works if your log implementation is logback).

Check https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/reference/html/#integration-with-logging